# Запуск .sh скрипта Linux Manjaro

Tags: linux, manjaro

Столкнулся с такой проблемой (Manjaro KDE), скачал архив с программой (Mozilla beta), разархивировал. Для установки нужно запустить .sh скрипт run-mozilla.sh, но при попытке запуска в терминале сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, как её решить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно, через sudo chmod a+x scriptname.sh

Comment: Тоже самое выдает

Comment: А запустите через ./scriptname.sh без sh

Comment: Всё равно Cannot execute

Comment: Тогда не знаю в чем дело :-)

Comment: @ИльяДьячков что это и откуда ? Только что скачал с офф. сайта beta тарбол и запустил: `./firefox`

Comment: https://www.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/channel/desktop/#beta

Comment: Скачал архив и разархивировал его

Comment: @ИльяДьячков отлично! Теперь осталось найти `firefox` и запустить его так: `./firefox`.

Comment: Почитайте https://askubuntu.com/questions/625595/why-cant-i-execute-run-mozilla-sh и https://forum.mozilla-russia.org/viewtopic.php?id=60786

Comment: Попробуйте запустить скрипт так `./run-mozilla.sh` (без sh в начале).

Comment: В каталоге, где расположен скрипт *run-mozilla.sh* выполните две команды: 1) *ls -l run-mozilla.sh* и *head -n5 run-mozilla.sh* И выложите сюда результат.

Comment: Ну, скачали 64-битную версию, а система 32-битная? Или вообще не под свою архитектуру?